# Queryset for counting the object created for last one day

Tags: django, django-orm

Lets say i have two model

```
class Testmodel1():
   amount = models.IntegerField(null=True)
   contact = models.CharField()
   entry_time = models.DateTimeField()

class Testmodel2():
   name = models.CharField()
   mobile_no = models.ForeignKey(Testmodel1)
```

and I am creating the object for this model`(Testmodel2)`. Now I want to find out the count of object`(Testmodel2)` created in last 24 hours by `mobile_no` field.

what could be the best way of making query.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where is the time stamp field?

Comment: @DuD. please check edited question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'd be better if you made the contact field into a `models.DateTime` field rather than a `models.CharFiel`d. If it were a DateTime field, you could do lte, gte, and other operations on it easily to compare it to other datetimes.

For example, if Testmodel.contact were a DateTime field, the answer to your question would be:

```
Testmodel.objects.filter(contact__gte=past).count()
```

If the contact field contains a string representing a DateTime, I'd recommend switching it over, since there's really no reason to store it as a string.

If you're unable to change these fields, unfortunately I don't think there's a way to do this on the database level. You'll have to filter them individually on the python side:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

results = []
past = arrow.utcnow().shift(hours=-24)
model_query = TestModel.objects.all()
for obj in model_query.iterator():
  contact_date = parse(obj.contact)  # Parse string into datetime
  if contact_date > past:
    results.append(obj)
print(len(results))
```

This will give you a list (note: NOT a queryset) containing all matching model instances. It'll be a lot slower than the other option would be, you can't edit the results afterwards with something like `results.filter(amount__gte=1).count()`, and it's not quite as clean.

That said, it'll get the job done.

**EDIT**
It occurs to me that this *might* be able to be done with annotation, but I'm not sure how that would be accomplished, or if it would even work. I defer to other answers if they can think of a way to use annotation to accomplish this in a better way, but stick to my original assessment that this should probably be a DateTime field.

**EDIT 2**
With a DateTime field now added on the other model, you can look it up across models like so:

```
past = arrow.utcnow().shift(hours=-24)
Testmodel2.objects.filter(mobile_no__entry_time__gte=past)
```